# splitting a vector into two in r

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm trying to split the below three elements:

`Bundle ISBN    Book 1 ISBN      Book 2 ISBN
9781454850908   9781454813613   9781454850168`

I want them to split as

`Bundle ISBN    Book ISBN
9781454850908   9781454813613
9781454850908   9781454850168`

Is there a function I can use ?

Comment: I think `data.frame(Bundle = x[1], Book = x[-1])` will do assuming `x` really is a normal vector.

Comment: Assuming `x`is a data.frame you can use `melt(x, "Bundle ISBN")` from package `reshape2` to get it in long format.

Comment: @rhole thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `tidyr` package, say your data.frame is called myDf:

```
library(tidyr)
gather(myDf, newVar, Book.ISBN, -Bundle.ISBN)[, -"newVar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

We could `split` the `vector` by the `names` of the `vector` after removing the numeric substring in that and convert the `list` output to a `data.frame`

```
data.frame(split(unname(v1), sub("\\d+\\s+", "", names(v1))), check.names=FALSE)[2:1]
#    Bundle ISBN     Book ISBN
#1 9781454850908 9781454813613
#2 9781454850908 9781454850168
```

#### data

```
v1 <- setNames(c(9781454850908,   9781454813613,   9781454850168), 
    c('Bundle ISBN',    'Book 1 ISBN',      'Book 2 ISBN'))
```